# How to insert complementary base in genomic dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Now, I have some genomic data which I have taken into a dataframe. So, as we know there are four bases - A,G,T and C. G and C are complementary to each other while A and T are complementary to each other.
So, the table that I have is and the column 'gDNA' is the result I want:

```
cDNA     region     strand    gDNA
c.58C>T  875487     +         875487C>T
c.87A>G  365412     -         365412T>C
```

So, the condition is that if strand is positive, then the exact "C>T" will be copied while if the strand is negative, A and G will be converted to their complementary bases - T and C and vice versa. I dont know how to do this. Do help me out guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate strings replacing complementary chars, where strand is not equal '+'

```
df['region'].astype(str) + \
df['cDNA'].where(df['strand'] =='+', \
                 df['cDNA'].replace('[A-G>]+$', regex=True) \
                           .replace({'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}, regex=True))


0    875487C>T
1    365412T>C
dtype: object
```

Comment: str[:-3] will not work, there might be cases where "c.546delAGG" or "c.876insAAAT".

Comment: It means, you need a criteria to get that part of a string

Comment: @SayantanGhosh I added regex